# Which thread invokes SensorEventListener.onSensorChanged

Tags: java, android

From my records it seems that SensorEventListener.onSensorChanged callback is 
called by the same thread that registered the callback. I.e there must 
be some message-queue synchronization going on in the background which 
allows the activitys UI-Thread to handle the callbacks.

That leads to my question: Is there a need to synchronize 
SensorEventListener.onSensorChanged with the activitys UI-thread, 
assuming that the activitys UI-thread registered the 
SensorEventListener?

I cannot find any documentation references, but can see various examples calling invalidate() unsychronized or synchronize the entire callback.

I used something along the lines of

```
Log.i(TAG, "" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

to retrieve threading information.

I'm running android 2.1 update1.

Best regards, 
Christoph